# Використання жіночих імен для утворення патроніма (по-батькові)

Tags: власні-назви

Чи використовуються в наші часи патроніми утворені від жіночих імен?

На жаль не пам'ятаю подробиць, але десь згадувався історичний випадок, коли дитині дали патронім по материнському імені, бо мати була королівського роду, а батько - ні.

Інший приклад - з літератури, де один (одна?) з героїв має по-батькові від імені своєї матері, бо вона - відьма (тобто знову - про успадкування по жіночій лінії).

Є лінія князів - Ольговичі, хоча ця назва утворена від імені [Олега Святославича, князя Чернігівського](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3_%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87_(%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)).

Пошук дає приклади жартівливих утворень ("якби ми жили при матріархаті"), але є і форми, подібні до утворених від жіночих імен.

Наприклад [Альбе́рт Катери́нович Ка́вос](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81,_%D0%90%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82_%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) - щоправда його батько-італієць мав ім'я Катерино.

[Данюк Віктор Тетянович](https://www.work.ua/ua/resumes/2932900/) - нажаль не міг знайти імені його батька, можливо це псевдонім, оскільки Віктор Тетянович - співак.

Чи використовуються такі "матроніми" у сучасній практиці? Наприклад, якщо ім'я батька невідоме, або через те що мати не хоче давати по-батькові засноване на імені батька?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Відповідь на це питання полягає радше в юридичній площині, аніж у лінгвістичній.

**[Сімейний кодекс України](http://zakon2.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/2947-14/page?text=%E1%E0%F2%FC%EA%EE)**, зокрема ст. 147 регулює визначення по батькові дитини

> Стаття 147. Визначення по батькові дитини
>
> 1. **По батькові дитини визначається за іменем батька.**
> 2. По батькові дитини, народженої жінкою, яка не перебуває у шлюбі, за умови, що батьківство щодо дитини не визнано, **визначається за іменем
>      особи, яку мати дитини назвала її батьком.**

Ст. 135 цього ж Кодексу визначає порядок запису про невстановлених батьків дитини

> Стаття 135. Запис про батьків дитини, якщо батьківство, материнство не
>   встановлене
>
> 1. При народженні дитини у матері, яка не перебуває у шлюбі, у випадках, коли немає спільної заяви батьків, заяви батька або рішення
>      суду, запис про батька дитини у Книзі реєстрації народжень провадиться
>      за прізвищем та громадянством матері, **а ім'я та по батькові батька
>      дитини записуються за її вказівкою.**
>
> У разі смерті матері, а також за неможливості встановити місце її
>   проживання чи перебування запис про матір та батька дитини провадиться
>   відповідно до цієї статті, **за заявою родичів, інших осіб або
>   уповноваженого представника закладу охорони здоров'я, в якому
>   народилася дитина.**
>
> 2. Якщо батьки дитини невідомі, державна реєстрація її народження проводиться **за рішенням органу опіки та піклування**, яким визначається
>      прізвище, власне ім'я, по батькові дитини і відомості про батьків.

Тобто, запис про батька має бути обов'язково, хай і зі слів матері, або за заявою родичів, або уповноваженого представника закладу охорони здоров'я, або за рішенням органу опіки та піклування.

Оскільки чинне українське законодавство (той же Сімейний кодекс) визнає **шлюбом**

> **"сімейний союз жінки та чоловіка, зареєстрований у органі державної реєстрації актів цивільного стану"** (ст.21),

то **батьком дитини може бути особа тільки чоловічої статі**.

**Отже, навіть якщо батько дитини записується зі слів матері, ім'я може бути тільки чоловічим.** Хіба що мати доведе, що жіноче ім'я, яким вона хоче записати по батькові дитини, насправді є чоловічим іменем.

Comment: Але все рівно цікаво як, наприклад, справляється з визначенням патронімів від жіночіх імен діаспора у Канаді

Comment: @Chizh не зовсім зрозуміло, за яких обставин у діаспорі щось буде відрізнятись від сучасних українських правил. Якщо щось і має відрізнятись, то хіба що відсутність вимоги мати патронім взагалі, або навіть відсутність змоги такий патронім вказати в офіційних документах.

Comment: в Канаді дозволені одностатеві шлюби, наскільки мені відомо

Comment: Власне, цитуючи ст. 21 Сімейного кодексу України, я й намагалася сказати, що в Україні не дозволені одностатеві шлюби (наразі).